# Plot data against time on x axis and adjust it in real time using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot real time serial data against time on x axis. 
I want x axis to change dynamically i.e. when I get new data the window length should remain same but the x axis should shift.

So far I have been able to plot the serial data sample sample points and I am not able to change the x axis but the y axis values keep on changing.

I took the help of the given code which I got from this forum itself

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random
from collections import deque
import numpy as np


def random_gen():
    while True:
        val = random.randint(1,10)
        yield val
        time.sleep(0.1)


a1 = deque([0]*100)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 10))
d = random_gen()

line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.show()

for i in range(0,20):
    a1.appendleft(next(d))
    datatoplot = a1.pop()
    line.set_ydata(a1)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

I have changed the random_gen() part for my case and I am plotting serial data but I am giving this code because otherwise I would have give to serial data in a file which will only make things complicated.

I found this code which can be used to find the time values

```
import datetime

dlist = deque([datetime.datetime.now()] * 100)

while 1:
    # collect the data .........

    dlist.appendleft((datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I have no idea how to change x axis dynamically.

I am new to python and there might be some things that I may be doing wrong so please ignore those

Please give some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I did search for matplotlib dynamic in google but I did not find anything which was useful for me, can you please mention the link

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: In the example you provided, the new data is inserted a the left hand side. But you write *"I want x axis to change dynamically i.e. when I get new data the window length should remain same but the x axis should shift."* Can you elaborate on what you have and what you want? And please separate your 2 questions in the text and logically. That helps everyone who reads it.

Comment: I am currently plotting serial data vs sample points. But I want to  plot serial data against real time( current date and time). I am receiving data at around 200 samples per second. Also regarding the code it is not the actual code which I am using, in my actual code I am using a1.extend(serial data) so the data is inserted from right side.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but couldn't you use `plt.xlim()` and update it every time you add new data? Using your example the loop would change to:

```
for i in range(0,20):
    a1.appendleft(next(d))
    datatoplot = a1.pop()
    line.set_ydata(a1)
    plt.xlim(0, 20 + i)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```